# The call is ambiguous between the following method

Tags: c#

I have and error telling that The call ambiguous between the following methods and properties `Clinic,Extensions.DrawImbeddedImage<System.Collection.Generic.IEnumrable<T>,System.Drawing.Printing..Margins)`and `Clinic.Extension.DrawImbeddedImage<T>(System.Collection.Generic.IEnumrable<T>,System.Drawing.Graphics,Int, Int,System.Drawing.Printing.Margins)`

[image]

Comment: The Screen shot error is in the "enter image description"

Comment: What is the type of ImbeddedImageList?

Comment: Can you share the methods signature?

Comment: sounds like you have 2 usings that are bringing in the same method signature.  Use the full name of one of them.

Comment: It´s really hard to get the code from your image. Please post your actual code direclt y into the question.

Comment: This looks like you might have different versions of the same assembly being referenced.  Try doing a Clean and Rebuild to see if that helps.

Answer (score -3):

One of your namespaces is slightly different to the other:

> Clinic.Extension**s**.DrawImbeddedImage,System.Drawing.Printing..Margins)

and

> Clinic.Extension.DrawImbeddedImage(System.Collection.Generic.IEnumrable,System.Drawing.Graphics,Int, Int,System.Drawing.Printing.Margins)

Notice the extra s on `Extensions` on the first one.

Comment: That's just a typo in the OP's question.  You should go by the image instead.

Comment: I just made it clickable so it takes you to the source which is readable.